# Big trouble : rpm empty db, install V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key BAD, YumRepo Error

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I'm little tired because I have spent hours solving problems, and can't find a solution on Centos 6.6.

I have many troubles:

- *rpm db is empty*: try googling, find restore process, but always empty
- *rpm acces* gives an error: `V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD`
- *yum acces* gives an error: `YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.`

How do you debug and use rpm?  I need to rollback on today's update of `nss-softoken` and `glibc` because they have broken all my `curl` https calls.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

First I restore a backup of my RPM db. And I follow this tutorial  [solved-bug-centos-yum-rpm-broken-by-nss-softokn-3](http://kiteplans.info/2015/01/15/solved-bug-centos-yum-rpm-broken-by-nss-softokn-3-14-3-19-el6_6-update-error-rpmts_hdrfromfdno-error-rpmdbnextiterator-header-v3-rsasha1-signature-key-id-bad/)

It solve the problem and I can go to sleep now ;-).

bug on : [nss-softokn-3.14.3-19.el6_6 updates may be broken](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=214791&f=13#p214791)

--- from the website fo who not like to click ;-) ---

To fix this you have to:

1. Manually download nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-19

   yumdownloader nss-softokn-freebl

or wget the RPMs

```
64-Bit servers / x86_64 run : wget ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-19.el6_6.x86_64.rpm

32-Bit Servers / i686 run : wget ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/centos/6.6/updates/i386/Packages/nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-19.el6_6.i686.rpm
```

Extract the RPM

```
64-Bit servers / x86_64 run: rpm2cpio nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-19.el6_6.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
32-Bit Servers / i686 run: rpm2cpio nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-19.el6_6.i686.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

Copy .libfreeblpriv3.* to correct location

```
64-Bit servers / x86_64 run : cp ./lib64/libfreeblpriv3.* /lib64
32-Bit Servers / i686 run : cp ./lib/libfreeblpriv3.* /lib
```

Rerun Yum Update to update nss-softokn-freebl and FIX YUM and RPM

yum update

If you still have problems you might have to reinstall yum as below for a 64bit server, 32bit servers will just need to locate the 32bit versions of the rpms! But most servers won’t need this:

1. wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.2.29-60.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
2. wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch.rpm
3. wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64.rpm

   1 rpm -ivh --nodeps yum-3.2.29-60.el6.centos.noarch.rpm 2 rpm -ivh
   yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch.rpm 3 rpm -ivh
   centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64.rpm

I have also had some questions about how to restore the rpmdb that got corrupted while trying to fix the problem, there are two ways:

Copy a good copy of the /var/lib/rpm folder over from an identical good server of from a backups – you do have backups right?

On good server or from backup:

```
tar -cf rpmbackup.tar /var/lib/rpm
```

Then send the tar over to the bad server

On broken server:

1. `cd /var/lib`
2. `mv /var/lib/rpm /var/lib/rpm.bak`
3. `tar -xf /location/to/rpmbackup.tar`

Then you should be good to go!

---

Comment: That fix worked on my red hat 6.6 64bit server as well. Had a call open to Red Hat on this and passed on that that fixed the issue. I have 3 lab and a couple test servers that auto update that bug messed up rpm and yum as well. Hope Red Hat fixes this soon. Anyone updating CentOS/RedHat 6 is going to mess up rpm/yum, rpmdb rebuilds did not work for me on this. That fix saved the day.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Ok updated for you Terdon